# GDI+ how to query a pixel

Tags: api, delphi, graphics, gdi+

I am using the GDI+ library for Delphi 6 by [progdigy.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20120215233625/http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=7) .

I loaded an image using `TGPImage.Create(AFilename)`.

The question is, how can I query a single pixel (RGBA values)? The object TGPImage does not seem to have something like that. The documentation in the library only links to the Microsoft documentation of GDI+, which is a broken link by now.

PS: I can draw the image by using

`TGPGraphics.Create(PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle).DrawImage(Image, GPRect(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight));`

but I don't know if this helps since I need to query only the pixels without needing to draw the whole picture.

Comment: [`This function`](http://pastebin.com/L7PvBL1b) borrowed from the `TGPBitmap` class should do what you want.

Comment: I have used GR32 for some projects, but for this project it heavily failed because of bad PNG transparency support. GDI+ worked perfectly and easy. I could use TBitmap or TBitmap32 (from GR32) to query the pixel, but I want to support formats like PNG correctly, and since I already use GDI+, it would be good if I can use the existing solution to query the pixels.

Comment: That surprises me I have to say. Anyway, GDI+ is well documented no?

Comment: @TLama: Thank you very much for this piece of code. It works! It is also an interesting method of having class helpers in Delphi 6 ;-) Of course, it needs a cast to the "new" `TGPImage`, but this is no problem since no fields have been added. Can you please post it as answer?

Comment: It's not a class helper, it is what is known as an interposer class

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you. I didn't knew that term "interposer class" yet. I should have written it differently. Of course I know that it is not a class helper since the class is not the same, but a different one with the same name and an added functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can borrow the `GetPixel` method from the `TGPBitmap` class, which is used just for getting pixel colors. To implement this method, you will need to subclass the original `TGPImage` class to get access to the protected `NativeImage` field (holding the pointer to the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object).

Here is an example using interposer class:

```
uses
  GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ;

type
  // we need to subclass the TGPImage to access the protected NativeImage field
  TGPImage = class(GDIPOBJ.TGPImage)
  public
    function GetPixel(X, Y: Integer; out Color: TGPColor): TStatus;
  end;

implementation

{ TGPImage }

function TGPImage.GetPixel(X, Y: Integer; out Color: TGPColor): TStatus;
begin
  Result := SetStatus(GdipBitmapGetPixel(GPBITMAP(NativeImage), X, Y, Color));
end;
```